# PDO Fetch Class as a grouped collection object rather than as individual objects in an array

Tags: php, class, oop, object, pdo

I'm developing a light ORM that uses a base model to fetch all rows from a database table. I have multiple models (Question, Answer, Comments) that extend the base model with a protected `$table` property declared in each model. This is my method for fetching table rows in the base model:

```
public function all() {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table}";
    $statement = $this->database->getConnected($this->connection)->prepare($query);
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Core\Database\Collection');
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll();

}
```

When I dump the results I get something similar to this:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(Core\Database\Collection)#31 (4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["title"]=>
        string(34) "What is your favourite video game?"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Core\Database\Collection)#244 (4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["title"]=>
        string(28) "What is your favourite food?"
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible that instead of being returned as an array or individual objects, if each collection object could be grouped together as one big collection object?

I know I can still get the results using `foreach` but just wanted to make it an actual collection rather than just an array.

**One big collection object**

```
object(Core\Database\Collection) {
    all: {
        Namespace\Question {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["title"]=>
            string(34) "What is your favourite video game?"
        },
        Namespace\Question {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "2"
            ["title"]=>
            string(28) "What is your favourite food?"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what _one big collection object_ looks like?

Comment: `PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows` So, your solution is to create a `while` and add every fetched record to your collection.

Comment: Does your Collection class have some kind of add() method? Should the individual items in the collection just be StdClass objects?

Comment: @AbraCadaver edited my question with a "collection object". Currently my collection class doesn't have any methods cause I'm not sure how to get the result set and assign in the way that I've described. Laravel does a similar thing which you can see at 1:05ish in this video: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

Comment: In that video there is an object with an `all` property which is an array of objects, similar to what you have.

Comment: But mine is returning 2 separate Collection instances/objects, that one just returns one single Collection instance with each result in an array. And the collection has no knowledge of what model it refers to, in that example it states the model 'App\Task', mine doesn't have that information anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that you are probably better off using your current array of objects.  However, you may be able to *fetch into* an existing object and have a magic `__set()` method to append the values to a named array:

```
class Collection {

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name[] = $value
    }
}
```

`PDO::FETCH_INTO` won't work with `fetchAll` as far as I know, so you need a `while`:

```
$collection = new Core\Database\Collection;
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $collection);
$statement->execute();
while($statement->fetch()){}
return $collection;
```

Should return something like:

```
object(Core\Database\Collection)#1 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    array(2) { 
        [0]=>string(1) "1",
        [1]=>string(1) "2"
    }
    ["title"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>string(34) "What is your favourite video game?",
        [1]=>string(28) "What is your favourite food?"
    }
}
```

Really the only other possibility is to have an object as you show in your edited example, with a property that is an array of objects.  You would do this similar to what you have.  Just fetch an array of objects of class `someNamespace\Question` and assign it to a property of another object of class `Core\Database\Collection`:

```
$collection = new Core\Database\Collection;
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'someNamespace\Question');
$statement->execute();
$collection->all = $statement->fetchAll();
return $collection;
```

Should return something like:

```
object(Core\Database\Collection)#1 (1) {
    ["all"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(someNamespace\Question)#1 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["title"]=>
            string(34) "What is your favourite video game?"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(someNamespace\Question)#2 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "2"
            ["title"]=>
            string(28) "What is your favourite food?"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know Laravel and the object/array syntax in the video seems to be homegrown so it's kind of hard to decipher.

Comment: That is very similar to what I'm after! Except I don't want each ID and Title groups into an array like that, I edited my question with a rough example of what I'd like to achieve. (and sorry for leaving after posting my question, I was in a rush to leave the office but wanted to get my question posted before I left, my apologies!)

Comment: Thanks, I’ll be able to try this out in the morning and let you know how it goes but if it returns something like in your edit it should be what I’m after

Comment: I think your initial response of using standard arrays is probably my best option. Laravel collections (scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-collections-php-arrays-on-steroids) are very complex. I think I'd need to incorporate something like this to get what I'm after: github.com/italolelis/collections. So assigning each fetchAll result to one of those collections and then assign that collection value to my own Collection class and return it. Seems excessive for what I'm after. Thanks for your help though, I know more about PDOs fetch method than I did before!